# How can I concatenate the following in Yii2?

Tags: php, concatenation, yii2

I have the following on my view file which I need to display as an image.

```
<img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>web/images/ad_image/<?php echo $ads['ads_id']; ?>.png " width="790" height="100" />
```

My `PATH` is `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl`. This does not work so I thought of using Yii alias `@web` and Html helpers like this:

```
    echo Html::img('@web/images/ad_image'.$ads['ads_id'].'.png', ['width' => 790, 'height' => 100]); ?>
```

That does not work too so I tried this and my image still does not show:

```
    $bf_ad = $ads['ads_id'];
    echo Html::img('@web/images/ad_image'.$bf_ad.'.png', ['width' => 790, 'height' => 100]);
```

What is the way to display this when I am loading from an array `$ads` which I get by `foreach (Yii::$app->params['ads_details'] as $ads) {`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$bf_ad = $ads['ads_id'];
echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/as_image/'.$bf_ad.'.png', ['width' => 790, 'height' => 100]);
```

Comment: Your answer helped me and since you were first I choose as best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/ad_image/'.$ads['ads_id'].'.png', ['width' => 790, 'height' => 100]);
```